# Why is my current stub in my RSpec test not properly stubbing the call to the method? Currently getting No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, stub, rspec3

- Ruby Version 2.7.2
- Rspec Version 3.12.0

---

So I'm currently working through App Academy Open and I'm at the point where we're creating a tic tac toe game. I've written out all my tests and they pass except for the last few.

I have successfully stubbed method calls in the past but for whatever reason, I'm not getting it to work here.

I have 3 classes `Board`, `HumanPlayer`, and `Game`. The method I am currently testing is `#play` from within the `Game`class:

```rb
def play
  while @board.empty_positions?
    puts @board.print
    position = @current_player.get_position
    @board.place_mark(position, @current_player.mark)

    if @board.win?(@current_player.mark)
      puts "Player #{@current_player.mark} wins!"
      return
    else
      switch_turn
    end
  end

  puts "The game ended in a draw!"
end
```

Here is what my test looks like:

```rb
RSpec.describe Game do
  let(:game) { Game.new(:X, :O) }
  
  # ...

  describe "#play" do
    before :each do
      @board = game.instance_variable_get(:@board)
      @board.place_mark([0, 0], :X)
      @board.place_mark([0, 1], :O)
      @board.place_mark([0, 2], :X)
      @board.place_mark([1, 0], :O)
      @board.place_mark([2, 0], :X)
      @board.place_mark([1, 1], :O)
      @board.place_mark([2, 2], :X)
    end

    it "should call Board#place_mark" do
      @current_player = game.instance_variable_get(:@current_player)
      allow(@current_player).to receive(:get_position).and_return([1, 2])

      expect(@board).to receive(:place_mark)
      game.play
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the `HumanPlayer#get_position` method:

```rb
def get_position
  puts "Player #{@mark}, enter two numbers representing a position in the format `row col`"

  position = gets.chomp.split(" ")

  if position.length != 2 || # not 2 characters
      position.any? { |n| n.to_i.to_s != n } # not all numeric

    raise "Invalid Position"
  end

  position.map(&:to_i)
end
```

Here is the `Board#place_mark` method:

```rb
def place_mark(position, mark)
  raise "Placement Invalid" if !valid?(position) || !empty?(position)

  row = position[0]
  col = position[1]

  @grid[row][col] = mark
end
```

So whenever I run the tests I always get the error:

```
Game Instance Methods #play should call Board#place_mark
Failure/Error: position = gets.chomp.split(" ")
     
Errno::ENOENT:
  No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - spec/2_game_spec.rb:85
# ./lib/human_player.rb:11:in `gets'
# ./lib/human_player.rb:11:in `gets'
# ./lib/human_player.rb:11:in `get_position'
# ./lib/game.rb:20:in `play'
# ./spec/2_game_spec.rb:92:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I believe I'm stubbing the `HumanPlayer.get_position` method to return `[1, 2]` when called but for whatever reason, the `Board.place_mark` method does not successfully place the piece on the board and thus, the `HumanPlayer.get_position` gets called again because of the loop and when it hits the `gets` call, it produces that error output.

I've tried stubbing the `gets` call with this:

```
it "should call Board#place_mark" do
  @current_player = game.instance_variable_get(:@current_player)
  allow(@current_player).to receive(:gets).and_return("1 2")

  expect(@board).to receive(:place_mark)
  game.play
end
```

I also tired `allow_any_instance_of(HumanPlayer)` but it just prints the board in an endless loop:

```
it "should call Board#place_mark" do
  @current_player = game.instance_variable_get(:@current_player)
  allow_any_instance_of(HumanPlayer).to receive(:get_position).and_return([1, 2])

  expect(@board).to receive(:place_mark)
  game.play
end
```

This is my first question on SO, so if there is anything I need to add please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the board's `@current_player` at that point of the test?

Comment: `#<HumanPlayer:0x00007fcde6aa2fd8 @mark=:X>` aka `@player1`... The `Game` class initializes 2 `HumanPlayer` objects in the `#initialize` method and sets `@player1` to be the `@current_player`.

Comment: "the Board.place_mark method does not successfully place the piece on the board" - is this a guess or have you verified this? If so, how?

Comment: What I think happens is the board _does_ get updated and then `switch_turn` makes another player current, on which `get_position` is not stubbed and this causes the error you see.

Comment: Verified with by placing a `binding.pry` statement after the call to `@board.place_mark(position, @current_player.mark)` from within the `#play` method. The `@board` shows all the placements from my `before :each` successfully, but doesn't show the current placement from my stub of `#get_position`.

I also checked what `position` was at this point, and it was indeed `[1, 2]` coming from my stub, I checked `@current_player` and that was indeed `@player1` and finally, the mark was indeed `:X`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes I agree, but the question I'm having is why the board is not being updated. Any ideas? I've racked my brain trying to find the disconnect but so far have been unsuccessful. :(

Comment: Ah, I see. When you do `expect(@board).to receive(:place_mark)`, you're stubbing out `place_mark` so it doesn't do anything. If you want to run the expectation AND keep the method working, do `expect(@board).to receive(:place_mark).and_call_original`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev that works! I'll dig into this a little to figure out why. I still have some other failing tests that are similar to the error I shared here so we'll see how much progress I make. Thanks!

Comment: Was able to get the rest of my tests passing. Question: I was always under the impression that using `allow(Object).to receive(:some_method).and_return(something)` was how you stubbed a method. But if I'm understanding the documentation I'm reading. Is `expect(Object).to receive(:some_method)` also stubbing the call to the original method and therefore why we need to call `#and_call_original`? Thanks.

Comment: It becomes obvious once you try to implement something like this yourself. How can RSpec know whether a method has been called or not? It replaces the method on this object with a "trap" that tracks how many times with what parameters it was called. By default, the trap only tracks calls. But you can tell to also invoke the original implementation too.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't figure out the `Errno::ENOENT` error, you might try a slightly different design, which I think is easier to stub.

```rb
class GameCLI
  def gets
    Kernel.gets
  end
end

class HumanPlayer
  def get_position
    # ..
    cli = GameCLI.new # or, pass cli instance as argument to e.g. get_position
    position = cli.gets # ..
    # ..
  end
end

RSpec.describe HumanPlayer do
  describe '#get_position' do
    it '..' do
      allow_any_instance_of(GameCLI).to receive(:gets).and_return('..')
      # ..
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This looks like a cool solution and something I might keep in mind for the future. Thanks for the suggestion.